# Google Calendar API conditionals

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to build conditions on a events-list query, but cant find documentation for specifying OR conditions, in this example:

```
gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            //'timeMin': from_datetime,     // pick everything since we already search by sharedExtendedProperty
            'showDeleted': false,
            'singleEvents': true,
            'maxResults': 100,
            'orderBy': 'startTime',
            **'sharedExtendedProperty': ['createdBy=someapp-alpha', 'createdBy=someapp-beta', 'createdBy=someapp-prod']**
        }).then(
            function (res) {
```

I'd like to be able to query for stuff with sharedExtendedProperty x OR sharedExtendedProperty y OR sharedExtendedProperty z ...
Adding both 3 possibilities to an array gives me no result. So I guess it is doing some AND instead of OR. So, any clues ????

Thank you !

Comment: if you cant find any documentation on it how do you know its supported?

Comment: I don't actually know, but it seems pretty odd if it's not supported ... The docs say "Extended properties constraint specified as propertyName=value. Matches only shared properties. This parameter might be repeated multiple times to return events that match all given constraints." ... I suppose this means AND is supported ? Why not support OR then ?

Answer (score 0):

### It is not possible to incorporate an `OR` query into the `calendar.events.list` request for extended properties

You need to do it manually by

- first making 3 separate list requests
- subsequently programmatically merge the results

Comment: Is there a way to use wildcards instead, or regular expressions ? All my extended properties are suffixed -beta; can I just query for 'sharedExtendedProperty': 'createdBy=*-beta' or something similar ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Also, as you can draw from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) for `q`: `Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any field, except for extended properties.`. You can file a feature request on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to implement a better query functionality, maybe it will eventually be incorporated.

Comment: This is an elegant and efficient way to perform multiple requests!